# Can I use a Mac Mini as an Airplay audio receiver?

Tags: software-recommendation, airplay

I don't have an AppleTV (yet), but I do have a Mac Mini hooked up to some decent speakers.  Is there something I can run on it, so that it acts like an Airplay audio receiver?

(Video support isn't important to me.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/) and [Reflector](http://www.reflectorapp.com/) allow your Mac to act as an Airplay receiver for audio or video. I'm not aware of an app that specializes in audio only Airplay, but either of those should do what you need.

Comment: +1 for AirServer, it does allow you to play audio, video and mirroring. (with 7 days trial period, nice people there)

Answer (score 26):

Proprietary:

- [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) - audio and streaming, Mac/Windows, $15
- [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) - audio and streaming, Mac/Windows/Android, $15
- [AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) - audio only, Mac/Windows/Linux, $30 for Mac/Win, $40 for both, free for linux
- [5KPlayer](https://www.5kplayer.com/airplay/) - audio and streaming, Mac/Windows, free

Open Source:

- [casualShare](http://sourceforge.net/projects/casualshare/) audio and streaming, Java + NodeJS, open source
- [AirStream (Ruby)](https://github.com/unused/airstream) - audio and streaming, source only
- [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/) - formerly XBMC, audio and streaming, Mac/Windows/Linux+, open source
- [Shairport Sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync) - audio only (multi-room), source only (C/make); this is the not-dead version of Shairport

Dead:

- [AirPlay for Totem](https://github.com/dveeden/totem-plugin-airplay) - audio and streaming
- [AirMac](https://code.google.com/p/airmac/), [on GitHub](https://github.com/firelizzard18/airmac/) - audio and streaming, source only (Objective-C)
- [AirStream (C#)](https://github.com/firelizzard18/airstream-media-player/) - audio and streaming, source only
- [Shairport](https://github.com/abrasive/shairport) - audio only, source only (C/make + perl)
- [Banana TV](http://bananatv.net/) audio and streaming, Mac, free, but *only supports iOS 4.2 through 4.3.5*

Answer (score 10):

Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) (which transmits Airplay from a Mac) is also very reliable, and includes [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) to receive Airplay from other sources. I recommend it highly.

Comment: Airfoil is for sending audio *from* the Mac, not to it. Good program though.

Comment: @CanuckSkier But you can send audio to a Mac using Airfoil and [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php)

Comment: Cool, didn't actually know that existed, thanks! If video isn't a requirement, that's a great option.

Answer (score 7):

From https://code.google.com/p/open-airplay/ (note they also support audio):

- [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/): The best app for turning your Mac into an AirPlay screen ($15)
- [Casual Share](http://sourceforge.net/projects/casualshare/): Mac AirPlay receiever
- [AirMac](https://code.google.com/archive/p/airmac/): Turns you Macintosh into an Airplay receiver (Objective C)
- [Airstream Media Player](http://code.google.com/p/airstream-media-player/): C# based AirPlay screen for windows and AirPlay server source code
- [Play2Wifi](https://code.google.com/archive/p/play2wifi/): An AirPlay server written in Python (< iOS 4.3)

And as Christian says, [AirFoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) should also do the trick ($25 / 10 minute trial).

I personally had problems with AirServer (kept crapping out) and Reflector only gives you a 10 minute trial, which isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

Xbmc supports being an airplay receiver and runs on macs.

http://xbmc.org/

Comment: Notice: it currently support audio only for >iOS7, and also its name is changed to Kodi.

Answer (score 0):

*adding this here in case anyone still stumbles onto this question post-2021:*

Apple added a native **[AirPlay to Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-sa/guide/mac-help/mchleee00ec8/mac)** feature in macOS 12 Monterey. It supports both audio and video, and is generally supported on devices introduced in 2018 or newer. The compatibility requirements are listed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689).

It's now a simple matter of enabling this setting in System Preferences → Sharing → AirPlay Receiver.

[image: Sharing PrefPane]