# Can my Mac be a wireless speaker?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

So there are several audio related things I do with my phone (which is not iOS) that I do while at my computer, and it'd be grand if I could play my podcasts or take my softphone calls on it. Is it possible with Bluetooth, or any other wireless method?

Comment: Got closed as a duplicate to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61956/can-i-use-a-mac-mini-as-an-airplay-audio-receiver, but the situation here is different (the phone is not running iOS).

Comment: Check out the [solution using Vysor](https://superuser.com/a/1548636/953657) from the question, [Playing music *from* bluetooth device *to* Mac OS? (Or Linux?)](https://superuser.com/questions/212806/playing-music-from-bluetooth-device-to-mac-os-or-linux).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any one OS X app that can do all of that for you, but here are a few recommendations.

**Turn your Mac into an AirPlay Speaker**

[Airfoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) from Rouge Amoeba works great for me to stream podcasts, music, radio, etc. from iOS devices to my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012). Note that you'll need to also install *Airfoil Speakers* which is a [free, separate download](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) (scroll down to "Airfoil Speakers for Mac"). The separate *Speakers* download requires the purchase of Airfoil, even though the download is free - think of it as an add-on to *Airfoil* even though it runs as a separate app. Further note that AirPlay is a one-way transmission and cannot be used as a speakerphone. See the next section...

**Turn your Mac into a Speakerphone**

Not sure what kind of softphone you have but check with your IT or phone system admin to see if there's a Mac client available. If there is, you'll also need configuration details from them so ask for that too (or have them set it up).

There are a couple of OS X apps that allow you to control your iPhone (and a few other types of phones) via Bluetooth but I've not had good luck with the reliability so I didn't purchase. I can't advise on those but a search online will turn up a few options if you'd like to try your luck. They've been around for awhile and are still under active development as far as I know.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried pairing an Android (4.2.x) phone ([Alcatel One Touch Idol X](http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_idol_x-5318.php)) to a MBP: no love.
I couldn't use the MBP as an audio output directly. It appeared to be a way to use the phone as a Bluetooth modem but I don't have a SIM for it so I did not try.

There are apps on the Google Play Store that allow Android to use AirPlay (I tried AllCast with dubious success, see http://gizmodo.com/how-to-stream-anything-from-android-to-airplay-1578516449), but this kind of convoluted "solutions" tend to break on each update of the streaming technology.
That said, in combination with the AirPlay software solutions described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61956/can-i-use-a-mac-mini-as-an-airplay-audio-receiver), it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would also theoretically work, just for audio output: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Junsun-Universal-3-5mm-jack-Bluetooth-Aux-Audio-Receiver-Adapter-Hands-free-Car-Kit-Music-Receiver/32838200156.html

You need to connect a bluetooth device that outputs audio with aux which you connect to your device as a microphone, and you play the sound from the microphone on the device - but at this point, it's probably more sane to just buy a bluetooth speaker