# How do I use a Mac as a wireless speaker for an iOS device?

Tags: macos, ios, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I know it’s possible to do this  when the device is wired to the Mac (using Quicktime’s record audio), but I haven’t found a way to do it wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61956/can-i-use-a-mac-mini-as-an-airplay-audio-receiver/190522) solves my use case; It doesn't work for apps not supporting AirPlay, unfortunately.

Comment: Any audio on iOS can be sent to AirPlay... the easiest way on iOS 11+ is to force touch/long press the playback module in Control Center and select the AirPlay icon in the top right.